# Will a function be called multiple times even if the parameter is the same (in a row)?

Tags: performance, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Let's say I have an assembly called `MyAssembly` with the class `MyClass` which has a `MyFunction(long timestamp)` method (it returns the datetime as a string in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mm:ss`). If I create a script for a job like this:

```
@outputData =
SELECT MyAssembly.MyClass.MyFunction(t1.timestamp).Substring(0,4) AS Year
      ,MyAssembly.MyClass.MyFunction(t1.timestamp).Substring(...) AS Month
      ,MyAssembly.MyClass.MyFunction(t1.timestamp).Substring(...) AS Day
      ,MyAssembly.MyClass.MyFunction(t1.timestamp).Substring(...) AS Hour
      ,MyAssembly.MyClass.MyFunction(t1.timestamp).Substring(...) AS Minute
      ,MyAssembly.MyClass.MyFunction(t1.timestamp).Substring(...) AS Second
 FROM @queryInput AS t1
```

Will the function be called multiple times or will the system be "clever" enough to call it only once and use the return value for the other columns? If no, what options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if ADLA is "clever" enough to handle your situation, but you can try using [custom processor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621322.aspx) instead. It will execute your method once for every row processed.

Your Process method should be like this:

```cs
public override IRow Process(IRow input, IUpdatableRow output)
{
     string timestamp = input.Get<string>("timestamp");
     var myFunctionResult = MyAssembly.MyClass.MyFunction(timestamp);

     output.Set<string>("Year", myFunctionResult.Substring(0,4));
     output.Set<string>("Month", myFunctionResult.Substring(...));
     //do this for other fields
     return output.AsReadOnly();
}
```

And in USQL your call should be like this:

```
@outputData = 
    PROCESS @queryInput
    PRODUCE Year string,
         Month string,
         ...
    REQUIRED timestamp
    USING new MyAssembly.MyProcessor();
```